# shell script is not same as single line grep command

Tags: grep, ripgrep

I have this shell script that works as expected.

```
#!/bin/sh
for ID in `cat comment_g.txt`
do
rg -w $ID wordsuc.txt >> out.txt
done
```

But the following grep command does not return a single record.

```
rg -w -f  comment_g.txt wordsuc.txt > out2.txt
```

Isn't this command same as the shell script?

---

Update:

works as expected:

```
# cat comment_g.txt
and

# cat ordsuc.txt
this
that
more and

# rg -w -f comment_g.txt ordsuc.txt
3:more and

# grep -w -f comment_g.txt ordsuc.txt
more and
```

---

Does not work same as above:

```
# cat comment_g.txt
सदस्य

# cat ordsuc.txt
सदस्य आणि
नोंद
पूर्व संकल्पनांना बळी पडले आहेत

# incorrect, should return 1 line
# rg -w -f comment_g.txt ordsuc.txt

# correct output:
# > out.txt
# sh run.sh
# cat out.txt
सदस्य आणि
```

Comment: Does `rg -f comment_g.txt wordsuc.txt` work?

Comment: They are certainly not equivalent. Please share more details, like small versions of the files used in your code.

Comment: You should copy/paste your shell script into http://shellcheck.net, learn about the problems with it, then fix them.

Comment: Using your examples, both cases work fine for me. Since your second example is the one with problems, maybe there is an encoding problem hidden somewhere.